# Traduzir uma pergunta é errado?

Tags: debate

Acabaram de fazer uma pergunta:

[Problema ao carregar o winbugs no R](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/131985/problem-with-r-code)

Ela estava em inglês. Tomei a liberdade de editá-la e traduzí-la. 
Isto é errado?

Fiz isso porque acredito que é melhor alguém traduzir a pergunta do que ela ser fechada e não ser respondida... O que acham?

Comment: É importante ter a certeza que o autor percebe português.

Comment: @Sergio http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/131985/problema-ao-carregar-o-winbugs-no-r#comment274610_131985

Comment: @Sergio Então se ele não falar português é melhor fechar a pergunta?

Comment: @DanielFalbel Se ele não entende português, como ele irá aceitar a resposta? Na minha opinião, perguntas em outras línguas devem sempre ser fechadas e, portanto, nunca traduzidas. Na melhor das hipóteses, movidas para a comunidade correta, se existir uma.

Comment: @DanielGomes Ele não irá aceitar mas, a pergunta dele pode ser útil para outras pessoas. Por exemplo, uma resposta na pergunta que eu traduzi poderá ser útil para alguém que fale o nosso idioma no futuro, você não acha?

Comment: @DanielFalbel Você tem razão quanto à utilidade de uma resposta no futuro. Porém, desta maneira, quem perguntou não obterá uma resposta (pois ela estará numa língua que ele não compreende), e terá que perguntar de novo no lugar certo (para onde a pergunta deveria ter sido migrada), sem falar do tempo que alguém "perdeu" respondendo. Se a pergunta ajudará alguém no futuro, significa que ela pode muito bem ser perguntada de novo, na língua certa.

Comment: @DanielGomes Concordo que ela poderia ser perguntada de novo na língua correta. O que não entendo é a desvanatagem para a comunidade de ter a pergunta traduzida e posteriormente respondida. Na minha opinião, devemos fechar apenas perguntas que geram problemas para a comunidade como perguntas que não estão claras, perguntas baseadas em opinião, etc. Perguntas em outra língua, se traduzidas, não geram nenhum problema para o SO, na verdade, acho que só têm a acrescentar.

Comment: Veja também: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1031/2652 e http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3923/2652

Comment: Relacionados também: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/648/2652 e http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1153/2652

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Está totalmente certo, desde que não mude a intenção do autor na tradução ou crie outros problemas.

É claro que ninguém é obrigado traduzir nada. Mas quem quiser fazer, e fizer certo, só estará causando um bem para a comunidade. E estamos aqui para ajudar a comunidade, não pessoas específicas. A ajuda individual é consequência, não causa. Fechar a pergunta que não está em português é algo normal também. E se não houver tradução por ninguém, ela tem que ser fechada, ou pela comunidade, ou por um moderador.

É claro que se achar que é um estrangeiro, pode não valer a pena o esforço, mas isto é raro. Ainda assim a comunidade se beneficiaria, mesmo que não o AP. Se a resposta não for útil pra ele, paciência. Aceitação não é um fim em si. Note que é extremamente raro, quase inexistente pergunta em outra língua ser de comunidade errada. Em geral é lusófono mesmo postando em inglês.

É sempre bom dar um alerta extra para a pessoa perceber que está em uma comunidade PT. Mas ele vai se aperceber de um jeito ou de outro (não consigo entender porque não entendeu antes).

A pergunta é de todos. Uma boa tradução nunca será um problema no site. Nunca poderá causar problemas para o AP. Se ele discordar ele estará contra as regras. O máximo que ele pode fazer é pedir para desvincular seu nome da pergunta. Ele só poderia reclamar se alterar o sentido. Ele querer teimosamente manter em outra língua é algo errado e no mínimo causará o fechamento. Há uma chance da pergunta receber negativos também. Mas não lembro de um caso sequer de alguém ir contra a tradução, isto é só hipotético. Pra falar a verdade o usuário negar a tradução eu consideraria vandalismo.

Você faz parte a comunidade, a pergunta é da comunidade, você tem o direito de traduzir.

A solução dada em outra resposta não resolve problema algum, só causa novos.

Comment: -2 por que não está certo?

Comment: não negative, mas do meu ponto de vista isso é apenas parte da resposta, o que o @Sergio disse é importante considerar.

Comment: Acredito que seja discordância apenas, por isso melhorei colocando motivos

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento é, mas ainda assim, não impede a tradução, e mesmo isso não costuma ser o caso. Procura quantos casos não eram lusófonos

Comment: @bigown quero dizer que o cara pode ter caido aqui por engano, seria melhor fechar, ou o AP remover e se for interessante alguem replicar.

Comment: Até concordo, mas isso não impede uma pessoa que queira traduzir de fazê-lo, não vejo motivos pra replicar, não vejo ganho nisso, mas se não tiver tradução, até é uma possibilidade, não disse que isso não é permitido. Eu acho que isso sim se parece com um roubo de pergunta alheia, como dito na outra resposta. Deve-se evitar.

Comment: O problema é a AP conflitar e remover depois justamente porque a pergunta esta em uma comunidade por engano, como eu disse sobre o comentário do @Sergio, tem que ver se o AP domina o idioma, a não ser que ele receba upvotes ou a uma resposta receba upvotes, a pergunta poderá ser deletada, pronto é trabalho jogado fora, eu não disse que é em todos casos, o que precisa é ter certeza, por isso tem caso que vale editar e tem caso que não.

Comment: Aí é só restaurar. A pergunta feita é da comunidade. Não precisa ter certeza, é adequado analisar cada caso, mas cabe apenas ao potencial tradutor decidir se ele deve ou não proceder a tradução.

Answer (score 2):

### Pequena coleção de motivos para não traduzirmos perguntas

> *Antes de tudo (e o mais importante!)*

- Mostre ao AP que esta é uma comunidade em português e que perguntas deveriam ser feitas nesta língua;
- Permita ao AP que edite sua própria pergunta (talvez ele seja
  bilíngue!);
- Sinalize a pergunta como fora de escopo por não estar em português;
- Deixe a massa descansar por alguns minutos... ;)

> *Traduções tomam tempo, e dinheiro. E tempo é dinheiro!*

- O tempo que gastamos traduzindo poderia ser usado para resolução de problemas;
- Essa pergunta poderia ser respondida sem passar por tradução e mais rapidamente, no site correto;
- Talvez já exista uma resposta para esta pergunta, no site correto.

> *A pergunta não é sua, e nem da comunidade<sup>1</sup>; ela é do AP*

- Ele pode não gostar da sua tradução e revertê-la, jogando fora o seu trabalho;
- Ele pode perceber que postou no site errado e apagar a pergunta, jogando fora o seu trabalho;
- O AP não entenderá o que você escreveu, e não terá seu problema solucionado, *parcialmente* jogando fora o seu trabalho (isso se ele não decidir, **então**, apagar a pergunta, jogando fora o seu trabalho).

> *O que fazemos com perguntas feitas em comunidades erradas?*

- Qualquer pergunta que pertença a outro site e seja feita no SOpt, é comumente migrada (e.g. perguntas do meta). É a mesma coisa para perguntas em inglês - elas **já pertencem** a outro site, o SOen.

> *Mas a pergunta é muito boa, e eu quero roubá-la pra mim!*

- Neste caso, [crie e responda sua própria pergunta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). Se o AP não poderá se beneficiar da pergunta traduzida e nem de quaisquer respostas feitas, nada mais justo que tirar o controle dele definitivamente (que injusto!);
- Ponto positivo: Ela será redigida de forma *ótima*. Não terá nenhum detalhe ou peculiaridade relacionada somente ao problema do AP, será mais clara e portanto servirá melhor à comunidade.

> *Mas se a pergunta for traduzida e tiver uma resposta, é melhor! Só temos a ganhar!*

- Certo, só temos a ganhar. Mas às custas do AP (ele ainda não teve seu problema solucionado, lembra?)
- A minha sugestão é que ajudemos ele primeiro. E ajudá-lo significa de alguma forma ter sua questão respondida, numa língua que ele entenda.

---

1. Ok, ela um dia será mais da comunidade do que do AP, *but not today!*

Comment: Discordo de cada palavra desta resposta. Este é um claro entendimento errado do que é esta comunidade.

Comment: São bons motivos, mas ainda não fui convencido de que traduzir é pior do que fechar a pergunta para o site. Pretendo continuar traduzindo os posts que eu achar adequado. Nada impede de avisar o AP de que sua pergunta foi traduzida porque o site não é em inglês... E ajudá-lo em inglês que nem o @Molx fez na pergunta que adicionei aqui.

Comment: Lembrando que a edição gera uma notificação para o OP.

Answer (score 1):

Não vejo problema algum em ser traduzida uma vez que a comunidade está em português.
Quando faço perguntas no stack em inglês, é feita no idioma que corresponde. Como bigwon disse: "...desde que não mude a intenção do autor na tradução..."